# I can't send more than 13 Mb to WCF Service (Maximum request length exceeded)

Tags: c#, wcf

I can't send more than 13 Mb to WCF Service. I get **Maximum request length exceeded** exception

Here is **CreateServiceHost** implementation

```
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
{

 IssuedSecurityTokenParameters itp = new IssuedSecurityTokenParameters(
                   "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV1.1");

            itp.IssuerAddress = new EndpointAddress(ConfigManager.ActAsSTS);
            itp.IssuerMetadataAddress = new EndpointAddress(ConfigManager.ActAsSTS + "/mex");

            // Create the security binding element
            SecurityBindingElement sbe = SecurityBindingElement.CreateIssuedTokenForCertificateBindingElement(itp);
            sbe.MessageSecurityVersion =
                MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10;


            // Create the HTTP transport binding element
            HttpTransportBindingElement httpBe = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
           httpBe.MaxReceivedMessageSize = httpBe.MaxBufferPoolSize = Constants.MaxFileSize;


           TextMessageEncodingBindingElement encodingElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
            XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas = encodingElement.ReaderQuotas;
            quotas.MaxArrayLength = quotas.MaxBytesPerRead = quotas.MaxStringContentLength = quotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = quotas.MaxDepth = (int)Constants.MaxFileSize;

            // Create the custom binding using the prepared binding elements
            CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(sbe, encodingElement, httpBe);


            EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(ConfigManager.BaseAddress));
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(contractDescription, binding, endpointAddress);
            host.Description.Endpoints.Add(endpoint);


            host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My,
                X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, ConfigManager.ServiceCertificateThumbprint);
}
```

Constants.MaxFileSize = 20971520 (20 Mb = 20 * 1024 * 1024)

All necessary settings  **MaxReceivedMessageSize, MaxBytesPerRead...** are set.

Also there is  `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="20480"/>` setting in the web.config file

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark since I haven't worked with WCF much and that was a while ago, but since you're using HTTP as your transport is it possible that the messages are being base64-encoded such that 13 MB of actual data is being encoded to 20 MB on the wire?  [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/e1f13641.aspx) doesn't mention anything like that, and I think base64 usually causes a size increase of 30%, so maybe that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve - you want to create WCF service that receives uploads of large files.

If so,perhaps using [WCF with streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx) bindings will help you achieve your goal.

A while ago I wrote a service that accepted large file uploads using configuration similar to this :

```
<netTcpBinding>
 <binding name="netTcpStreaming" sendTimeout="00:15:00" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483648">
          <security mode="None" />
  </binding>
</netTcpBinding>
```